# Not able to go back on clicking back arrow in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                Log.d("on","back pressed");
                return true;
           }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Not able to go back when clicking on back arrow in action bar.Not even the method is not called. My class extends AppCompatActivity.
Anybody plz help me to solve this issue

Comment: try with android.R.id.home instead of R.id.home

Answer (score 1):

The correct item ID for the back button is `android.R.id.home`, once you change `R.id.home` to `android.R.id.home`, the code should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you created Menu of BackButton.. because if not thats why it's not working.. may be you created Imagebutton or Imageview for Back

Answer (score 0):

**Try these code Once**`

```
 @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
   return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

starting from enabling the back button, don't if you are using the AppCompatActivity, if you are using same then use :

```
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Listen for click events on android.R.id.home as seen you are using R.id.home replace that like this :

```
          @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
          if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
          // if your previous activity is present in stack(Means Not finished) then prefer finish();
          finish();
          //Or You can use same method you mention
           onBackPressed();
           }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
          }
```